# Serve dynamic content based on authentication state with Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to serve dynamic content using Firebase Functions based on if the user is authenticated or not?

Basically, how do I get the authentication state of the current user without passing in a request in Firebase Functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The client has to [send an id token to the backend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), whether it is Cloud Functions or some other service.  There is no way to avoid doing that if the backend needs to know something about the user signed in to the frontend.

You can use a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to automatically send this ID token from your client code, when the user is signed in, but it is still always being sent.  In every other case, you must arrange to send this token yourself.